# Does .Net DataContract have to include all members from Json?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, datacontract

I am using .Net 3.0 to deserialize two different json strings to a c# class.  Here is some sample json:

```
{"studio" : "mystudio", "name" : "John Doe"}
{"studio_name" : "mystudio", "name" : "John Doe" }
```

Notice that the json strings are different.  Can I create a class like the following, with studio and studio_name as DataMembers?:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class StudioMeta
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Studio_Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Studio { get; set; }
    }
```

If I just include one data member from each json string, will it properly deserialize?  Or is this illegal?

Also, if all I'm doing is deserializing, do I need the `DataContract` and `DataMember` modifiers?

Comment: You might consider using [json.net](http://json.net), and then you wouldn't have to use those attributes at all.

Comment: Yeah I would like that very much, but I'm not in charge.

Answer (score 0):

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx). You can use the

> [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]

field (default: false) and

> [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]

property. In your case, serialization and vice versa should work fine.

Comment: what is `field (default: false)`?

Comment: I mean that IsRequired is by default false. So if the JSON text does not include that member, .NET will still deserialize the object correctly.

Comment: But you're setting IsRequired to true, doesn't that mean it will break when it's not in the JSON text?